# Mysql jconnector spends 50% time in com.myql.jdbc.utils.ReadAheadInputStream.fill()

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I am profiling my application which uses Spring, Hibernate, and mysql-java-connector. The VisualVM shows that more than 50% of CPU time is spent in `com.myql.jdbc.utils.ReadAheadInputStream.fill()` method when there are 1000 parallel connections doing read.

Is there any optimization to make it faster?

Comment: Do you have your logging set at debug level? Are you doing something with those connections or just doing dummy selects? Also, this class delegates to another input stream. It would be helpful to see a stack trace from one of the calls.

Comment: @Augusto I am doing real queries which returns about 200 rows every time. What logging do you mean? on hibernate or on mysql? The real method is java.net.SocketInputStream.read. I google it, but not many hints on how to improve it.

Comment: It does sound as it's just waiting for the DB to return data. The problem might be in the DB itself, have you seen any usage data from MySQL and the box where it's running? A 1000 concurrent connections will use quite a lot of memory.. and if it has to access disk for those queries, then the DB will take quite a while to respond.

Comment: @Augusto yes, it seems to be. I changed to a more powerful machine, the performance is getting higher

Comment: any luck solving this issue?

Comment: is there any way that you could use a ConnectionPool (e.g. the connections are coming from one Host) like DBCP or C3P0 ? Updating to MySQL 5.6.26 could help too!

Comment: That is common when using Hibernate as it holds the connection/stream open as part of it's real time population.   This and a lot of other details are much less efficient when using Hibernate.

Comment: It spends 50% of its time reading from the network. That's not anything you can speed up by any means other than using a faster network or returning smaller query results.

Comment: @BrianC Is there any way to optimize Hibernate itself for this case?

Comment: No, Hibernate is the problem.

Comment: I had the same feeling but looking in the code of this function would not make any sense to eat CPU by itself. I think its just IO wait but wrongly reported. On ther other hand i also see a high CPU load.

Answer (score 3):

VisualVM counts a thread as using CPU time whenever the JVM thinks it's runnable. This means that any thread not waiting on a lock is considered runnable, more or less, including threads waiting for I/O in the kernel! This is where the large amount of CPU usage in `com.myql.jdbc.utils.ReadAheadInputStream.fill()` is coming from. So instead of a CPU problem you have an I/O problem.

There are some things you can do on the JVM side, but not a lot of straightforward optimizing:

1. Tweak the connection pool size. 1,000 concurrent queries is a *lot*. Unless your MySQL instance is truly massive it's going to have trouble handling that level of load, and eat up a lot of time just switching between queries. Try dropping the pool size, to 250 or even 50, and benchmark there.
2. Do fewer or smaller queries. If your app is small it might be trivially obvious that every row from every query is necessary, but maybe your app is bigger than that. Are the different places that query the same data, or can two different queries be combined into one that will satisfy both?

Answer (score 2):

On top of the other suggestions, consider also experimenting with a much lower amount of connections (i.e. 20).
It's very possible that the overhead of handling such a large amount of open connections is slightly fooling your profiling observations.

Not least, make sure you're using a recent version of Hibernate ORM.
We made version 5.0+ much smarter than previous versions, especially regarding performance improvements ;-) Improvements are applied daily, so keeping up to date or at least trying the latest might be an easy win.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question without additional information. Here some information needs that should be fulfilled before.

1. is it your estimate of CPU time absolute or relative? If `fill()` method uses half of CPU time available to system it seems strange. But if this number was get using VisualVM which reports usage time relative to time spent in application, it just may be the rest of your application is not doing significant work?
2. Do these profiling measurements confirmed using system level tools? You can use `pidstat`, `mpstat` and `sar` to crosscheck if you on a Linux. I've seen VisualVM marked time spent in `SocketInputStream.socketRead0()` method as a CPU time, which was not confirmed by `pidstat`. I guess it's consequences of some measurement approximations in VisualVM itself or JVM behavior. So it's always good idea to crosscheck using OS tools.