# Why does performance of this batch insert degrade in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for help understanding why this insert query gets slower as the table size grows.

The query is a batch insert of 1k rows.  By batch i mean multiple 'values' rows as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5526937/690431).

There is also a longblob field in the table.  Typical size of blob field data is rather small at around 2kb (but it can be much larger).

The image shows the results of SHOW PROFILE for the query **when inserting into an empty table vs inserting into a table which already had 1 Million rows**.  The FK tables are nearly empty in both cases.

[image]

Table structure (column names changed for anonymity):

```
CREATE TABLE `MyTable` (
 `modifiedtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `column1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `column2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `column3` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
 `column4` decimal(20,5) NOT NULL,
 `column5` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
 `column6` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
 `creationtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `version` decimal(20,5) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `column7` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
 `column8` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
 `schemaless_attrs` longblob,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `AK_MyTable` (`column4`,`column8`),
 KEY `FK_MyTable_column3` (`column3`),
 KEY `FK_MyTable_column5` (`column5`),
 KEY `IDX_ManagedBaseDataItem_column1` (`column1`),
 KEY `IDX_MyTable_column3` (`column3`),
 KEY `IDX_MyTable_column4` (`column4`),
 KEY `IDX_MyTable_status` (`status`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The query below is a typical example.  Note: In the real query there are 1000 rows of 'values'.

```
insert into `MyTable` (`creationtime`, `modifiedtime`, `column8`, 
`column5`, `column1`, `schemaless_attrs`, `version`, `column3`, 
`column6`, `column2`, `column4`, `status`, `column7`, `id`) 
values ('2015-07-01 14:47:41.259', '2015-07-01 14:47:41.259', 
'single', 'single|MyApp|0', 'MyProduct', 
_binary'a serialized Java ojbect which is usually around 2k in size', 
0, 'single|column3|cfd3229a-b424-41cc-b140-08cd92241064', 
null, 'en', 1000001, 'PENDING', 'ManagedAppEntity', 
'single|ManagedAppEntity|b095c316-293b-4a28-9a18-5422dd66eadd')
```

**Important Notes:**

- We have another app which makes *nearly* the same insert query into the same table structure.  The insert time never degrades for the other app as the tables grows.
- Since the other app uses the same exact MySQL db, same table (with the exception of 'version' field which is new), and and nearly the same insert query I'd prefer not to focus on db config such as 'innodb_buffer_pool_size', indexes, moving blog to another table, etc.
- While there is surely room for improvement in the db config, the other app is not showing the slowdowns. I'm trying to achieve similar performance with the same db config.

**Related Questions:**

- I have previously asked two related questions around this problem.  To be clear, I'm not trying to spam SO with Questions around this topic but I've had a hard time pinning down whether the slowdown is coming from the app or the db.  This seems like a good specific question for SO.  Anyhow, the other questions are:

  - [Question #1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31083896/does-column-order-matter-when-inserting-blobs): A (perhaps naive) question around whether the column order makes a difference when inserting blobs.  Comments on this q indicate "no".
  - [Question #2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152076/why-are-the-insert-batch-times-increasing): A question that is focused more on the dev stack for the app in question.

Comment: The fast app and slow app are working against the same exact table, or similar tables?

Comment: Exact same except for 'version' column

Comment: So they are similar. Do a textual dump of each structure with indexes not a picture. Tell number of rows in each. Describe timings against each telling number of rows processed

Comment: We know they are NOT the same table

Comment: Thx for providing the Durations table

Comment: Assuming the indexes are all the same on both tables (important, since more indexes means slower updates) the size of the buffer pool relative to the working data set becomes relevant if the better-performing table is (counterintuitively) getting *more* usage, since a busy table's pages are more likely to already be *in* the buffer pool when inserts are happening.